# Python, comparing JSON iterations with multiple keys and values

Tags: python, json, parsing, for-loop, key

I'm having trouble comparing 2 iterations from a JSON for matching `asset Ids` and print values of all matched assets, having multiple keys and multiple values I'm getting confused on to do this effectively.

Is there way I can compare :

> assetId = key

and

> asset = value["asset"]["id"]

from different iterations and if any of all assets match, then print the (item, listingId, subTotal) of all matched asset numbers ?

Not the complete JSON but the part I need to work with :

```
{ 
  "success": true,
  "more": false,
  "listinginfo": {
    "719811220882156383": {
      "listingid": "719811220882156383",
      "converted_price": 657,
      "converted_fee": 97,
      "asset": {
        "currency": 0,
        "appid": 730,
        "contextid": "2",
        "id": "4495490578",
        "amount": "1",
      }
    },
    "719811220882158733": {
      "listingid": "719811220882158733",
      "converted_price": 49,
      "converted_fee": 6,
      "asset": {
        "currency": 0,
        "appid": 730,
        "contextid": "2",
        "id": "2778717097",
        "amount": "1",
      }
    },
  "purchaseinfo": [    
  ],
  "assets": {
    "730": {
      "2": {
        "4495490578": {
          "currency": 0,
          "appid": 730,
          "contextid": "2",
          "id": "4495490578",
          "classid": "1389958217",
          "instanceid": "188530139",
          "amount": "1",
          "status": 2,
          "original_amount": "1",
          "background_color": "",
          "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5lpKKqPrxN7LEmyVQ7MEpiLuSrYmnjQO3-UdsZGHyd4_Bd1RvNQ7T_FDrw-_ng5Pu75iY1zI97bhLsvQz",
          "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5lpKKqPrxN7LEm1Rd6dd2j6eQ9N2t2wK3-ENsZ23wcIKRdQE2NwyD_FK_kLq9gJDu7p_KyyRr7nNw-z-DyIFJbNUz",
          "name": "AK-47 | Redline",
          "name_color": "D2D2D2",
          "type": "Classified Rifle",
          "market_name": "AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)",
          "market_hash_name": "AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)",
          "owner": 0
        },
        "2778717097": {
          "currency": 0,
          "appid": 730,
          "contextid": "2",
          "id": "2778717097",
          "classid": "720294710",
          "instanceid": "188530139",
          "amount": "1",
          "status": 2,
          "original_amount": "1",
          "background_color": "",
          "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgposr-kLAtl7PLZTjlH7du6kb-FlvD1DLPUl31IppF3jLvC8d2i2lKx-BVpN2_3IdPDcwJqMF7Z_VS7yOy-0JbuucvKyiF9-n51aSXb4FU",
          "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgposr-kLAtl7PLZTjlH7du6kb-FlvD1DLPUl31I18lwmO7Eu9jzjga3r0JrYT-mJ9CQJgA6ZA2G-1XqkOjmgpO5tZ-YnHIxv3Yh5izD30vgRbaAlsY",
          "name": "Desert Eagle | Naga",
          "name_color": "D2D2D2",
          "type": "Restricted Pistol",
          "market_name": "Desert Eagle | Naga (Battle-Scarred)",
          "market_hash_name": "Desert Eagle | Naga (Battle-Scarred)",
          "owner": 0
        },
        "4487026121": {
          "currency": 0,
          "appid": 730,
          "contextid": "2",
          "id": "4487026121",
          "classid": "1428441554",
          "instanceid": "0",
          "amount": "1",
          "status": 2,
          "original_amount": "1",
          "background_color": "",
          "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFMu1aPMI24auITjxteJwPXxY72AkGgIvZAniLjHpon2jlbl-kpvNjz3JJjVLFG9rl1YLQ",
          "tradable": 0,
          "name": "Operation Breakout Weapon Case",
          "name_color": "D2D2D2",
          "type": "Base Grade Container",
          "market_name": "Operation Breakout Weapon Case",
          "market_hash_name": "Operation Breakout Weapon Case",
          "owner": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

The Parsing I was able to do so far:

```
            InfoJson = json.loads(response)
            assetInfoJson = InfoJson["assets"]["730"]["2"]
            for key, value in assetInfoJson.iteritems():
                assetId = key
                try:
                    image = value["icon_url"]
                    item = value["market_hash_name"]
                except KeyError:
                  continue

            listingInfoJson = InfoJson["listinginfo"]
            for key, value in listingInfoJson.iteritems():
                listingId = key
                try:
                    subTotal = value["converted_price"]
                    feeAmount = value["converted_fee"]
                    asset = value["asset"]["id"]
                except KeyError:
                  continue
            if assetId == asset:
                print ("Found Matching asset :",assetId)
                print ("Found Matching name : %s, listingid : %s, subtotal : %s" % (item, listingId, subTotal))
```

Unfortunately this way doesn't compare both complete lists for matching Asset ids, only when the last assetId matches the first asset from both iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the for loops incorrectly. Since both loops are at the same level, the values of `assetId`, `image` and `item` will be the value assigned the last time the loop ran successfully.

A similar problem is happening with the second for loop.

Finally, your if condition will only compare the values of the last element in each list.

A solution to your problem would be to use the `in` operator to find the given ID in the proper dictionary

```
InfoJson = json.loads(response)
assetInfoJson = InfoJson["assets"]["730"]["2"]
listingInfoJson = InfoJson["listinginfo"]

for key, value in listingInfoJson.iteritems():
    listingId = key
    try:
        subTotal = value["converted_price"]
        feeAmount = value["converted_fee"]
        asset = value["asset"]["id"]
    except KeyError:
      continue

    if asset in assetInfoJson:
        # Get asset details if it's present in the assetInfoJson dict
        assetInfo = assetInfoJson[asset]
        try:
            image = assetInfo["icon_url"]
            item = assetInfo["market_hash_name"]
        except KeyError:
          continue

        print ("Found Matching asset :",assetId)
        print ("Found Matching name : %s, listingid : %s, subtotal : %s" % (item, listingId, subTotal))
```

Comment: awesome, totally failed to think of it this way ! This worked great to print matching info, but I want to ask ? How can I use all matched data outside the loop ? For example, in another function outside the loop, do `print (float(subTotal + feeAmount), asset)` of only matched items ?

Comment: @MarieAnne, You'll need to [build a list](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm), adding the items you want to reference later, you could save IDs only or full details. The you'll use that list to print the relevant information